# How to add custom calendar with add event options inside app ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, calendar

How to add custom calendar with add event inside app ios? Is it possible to add? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 First Add EventKit Framework.

 Second Add #import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
```

and than you can use this below code to add the events data in your app:

```
// Create Event
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];


NSDateFormatter *dateFormats = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormats setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
date1 = nil;
date2 = nil;
date1 = [dateFormats dateFromString:startTime];
date2 = [dateFormats dateFromString:endTime];

event.title  = @"Test Event";
event.allDay = NO;
event.startDate = date1;
event.endDate = date2;
event.notes = @"Nice Event on Tuesday";
event.location = @"NewYork, USA";

//put here if start and end dates are same
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;

[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];

if(err == noErr)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Display/dismiss your alert

        NSString *title = nil;
        NSString *description  = nil;
        NSString *cancelButton = nil;

        title = @"Event added - successfully!";
        description = nil;
        cancelButton = @"OK";

        UIAlertView *alerts = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                         message:nil
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:cancelButton
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alerts show];
        [alerts release];
    });
}
```